# Is my Mac Mini too slow for Mojave?

Tags: mojave, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini end 2014, 2,6GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3 with Mojave.

I spend hours (well ok, minutes) watching the coloured spinning wheel whenever I'm launching something, or even coming back to a window. Memory is never fully used, nor the CPU.

It's specially slow when I start a session.

Is my Mac just too slow for Mojave?

Comment: Doesn't sound like the Mac Mini is too old, but more so you're asking if it's too slow. It sounds like there's something else going on. Maybe get diagnostics run on it at an Apple Store or AASP. Have you tried backing it up via Time Machine, erasing it, and seeing how it operates without your data on it? Do you have a HDD or SSD for your hard drive?

Comment: do you have many startup items?  I have an old iMac and it was running slow due to a 3rd part login item. I started in safe mode and speed problem didn't show up! I got rid of some login items and the problem disappeared.

Comment: FWIW/ if this Mac Mini has a spinning disk, it is going to be slow. I was able to prolong the useful lifetime of a similar Mac Mini by installing a SSD.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, I'd try to get an appointment at an apple store for a diagnostic. I used to have startup items form old software installations that were causing some delays at startup but I remove them.  I have and HDD.